# How to find which processes are started/utilized when USB drive inserted

Tags: debian, security, usb, apparmor

I want to restrict the processes involved in handling removable storage via AppArmor on a Debian system.

Which processes are used by Debian when a removable storage device (USB) is inserted? Which tools and methods could I use to discover this locally (newly spawned processes possibly)?

Comment: `udev` is definitely one of them

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following **udev** rule to detect when the **usb** is plugged, then one the usb is plugged a **symlink** to the **usb device** will be created under **/dev/tusb** and `/tmp/usb_plugged.sh` script will be executed to get the list of processes:

1- Create the udev rule under `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", SYMLINK+="tusb", RUN+="/tmp/usb_plugged.sh"
```

2- Add the following script`/tmp/usb_plugged.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Wait for certain time in case of autorun
sleep 10
## Get list of processes using the usb device block symlink and write the output to /tmp/processes.txt
lsof -Fp /dev/tusb | tr -d '^p' > /tmp/processes.txt
```

3- Add execute permission on the script:

```
chmod +x /tmp/usb_plugged.sh
```

4- Finally, plug your usb to test.